# clicking button with selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

I am trying to click a button with selenium webdriver. But not managing to identify the button. 
This is my code: It returns an error message

> NoSuchElementException: Message: u'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="artifactContentList"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/content-dataset-actions/content-dataset-actions/section/section/button[2]"}\n  (Session info: headless chrome=81.0.4044.138)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.39.562718 (9a2698cba08cf5a471a29d30c8b3e12becabb0e9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18363 x86_64)'

```html
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from splinter import Browser
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import csv
chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= "C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe",   chrome_options=chrome_options)  

def open_url(): 
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= "C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe",   chrome_options=chrome_options)  
    browser.get("https://app.powerbi.com/groups/xxxxs")
    python_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/root-downgrade/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/landing/div/div/div/ng-transclude/landing-route/list-proxy/content-list/div/main/dataset-list/div/virtual-scroll/div[2]/div/div[3]/content-dataset-actions/content-dataset-actions/section/section/button[2]')   
    print(python_button)
    python_button.click()

    browser.quit()


open_url()
```

This is the full element:

```html
<button class="refreshNow pbi-glyph pbi-glyph-refresh" localize-tooltip="RefreshNow" ng-if="::$ctrl.canRefreshNow" ng-click="$ctrl.runAction($ctrl.RefreshNow)" aria-describedby="ModeldatasetMenu4" use-tooltip-as-aria-label="" title="Refresh now" aria-label="Refresh now" pbi-focus-tracker-idx="54"></button>
```

Comment: find_elements will return a list of references to DOM objects.  (the click method will be available on each item in the list.  Maybe you just need find_element instead?

Comment: thanks! that just gives me an error of 'no such element'. i guess i need another way to identify the element

Comment: I guess to get to the desired element we need to login through valid credentials. Do you have a set of demo credentials?

Comment: I would shorten your XPATH to something like "//button[contains(@title, 'Refresh')]"

Comment: the issue was logging in with credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

python_button = browser.find_element_by_class_name('refreshNow')